# Custom Emulated Device to be 150% scaling for Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a very specific screen size that I am designing to: 1920x1080 with Windows' 150% scaling applied.

I use Chrome Dev Tools and want to use it's emulated devices feature to emulate this screen size but I don't understand how I should configure the custom device to match. The Device Pixel Ratio doesn't match up with the display scaling in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so I got it. I used a screen resizer extension to see what the viewport size is when I set my screen to that resolution and determined that I just need to configure chrome to use a **DPR of 1**, with a resolution of **1279x589** (if bookmark bar is enabled in chrome, otherwise height would be a little more.)